# How to hide the root folder in a workspace with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a workspace instead of a folder the workspace shows the root folder. Is there a way to hide this? I want to use a workspace so I can have workspace specific extensions and settings. Not as a multiproject space.

Workspace View

[image]

Folder View

[image]

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of VSCode workspaces that they're multi-root? So I don't think it makes sense to hide the folder to be honest, otherwise you can just use a folder workspace.

Comment: I want to use a workspace so I can have workspace specific extensions and settings. Not as a multiproject space.

Comment: Ah yeah, different ‘profiles’ for vscode basically, that would be a nice feature

Comment: Can't you just open the folder without the workspace? You can still have specific settings/extensions (though they'll be defined in the .vscode folder, which maybe you're trying to avoid?)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny That would be fine but i'm not sure how do do install specific extensions that way.

Comment: @rwilliams what do you mean by install? My understanding is that extensions are installed globally, but can be enabled/disabled per-workspace, and you can set recommendations (for ex. see https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/.vscode/extensions.json which recommends extensions and works without a workspace)

Comment: I'm not sure, it's working for you or not(Because you don't need root folder and need files stored inside it) but check it once hopefully it gives some idea or other ways. http://donovanbrown.com/post/Hide-folders-in-Visual-Studio-Code-Explorer

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. Open your project folder in VS Code as a folder
2. Save the project workspace in myProject.code-workspace
3. Close your worksapce
4. Open your project folder as a folder again (at this point, the root folder is invisible)
5. Click "File > Save Workspace As..." to overwrite myProject.code-workspace
6. Now, you can continue to work in VS Code in "workspace" mode

This approach is a little bit more work (these 6 steps took me 10 seconds), but it seems to be the open approach that works (ever since the original poster asked this question in December 2019; today is already in December 2023).

As long as you keep VS Code open, you don't have to repeat the 6 steps above.  For me, I restart my laptop once a week, so I only have to repeat these 6 steps once a week.

I like the benefits of working in "workspace" mode, which saves your editor and terminal layouts.  At the same time, similar to the original poster, I dislike the root folder in the primary side bar, which takes up 1 line of valuable vertical space and some horizontal space as well.  For people working on a 14" or 15" laptop, removing the the root folder provides quite a lot of productivity boost (since you don't have to constantly scroll left/right to see the files).

Edit: Step 5 might change the whitespace formatting of your .code-worksapce file when you overwrite it.  If you don't want it to be changed, you can always use GitHub to revert the .code-workspace file (and VS Code is still opened in "workspace" mode after reverting).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out [Make Hidden](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devine-davies.make-hidden). This worked for me.

Comment: Tried it. I can't seem to get it to work the way i want it. Were you able to achieve what i'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the folders you want to see in a subfolder (e.g. `src`), then open your `*.code-workspace` file and in `"folders": {}` set `"path": "./src"`.

Alternatively you could create the workspace above your `cds` folder and execute the same steps as above but use `"path": "./cds"` and don't create the extra folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the easiest way of doing the same is by going to the workspace and openong your VSCode in that location using `code ./`
This should just work fine I guess :)

Comment: This is fine for opening the folder but it doesn't open it as a workspace

Answer (score 0):

you can hide it by going to **settings** of VS code (commonly used) you'll find **files:Exclude** below. add `**/cds` to the list of hidden files and refresh your files. it should work

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect on the file tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to the `code-workspace` file and removed the default `"folders": [{ "path": "." }]` and instead listed each of my subfolders.

```js
"folders": [
    {
      "path": "./folder-a"
    },
    {
      "path": "./folder-b"
    },
]
```

This removed the root folder from the treeview.